# Timer thread impact in android application performance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm designing an app in which I move from one activity to another in a specified time using a timer...
When I move to one activity, in that timer I start another activity and so on.

My question is, what will happen to the current thread once I move into another activity. Will it run in background? If so how can I kill it?

Will this type of design will effect my application performance? If yes, what is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The same UI thread handles all Activities in your app so you don't need to kill any thread.

If you don't need Activity A anymore when you start Activity B, you can call finish() to end it, at the same time you launch the new one.

If you want to keep previous activities in the stack to be able to come back to them later, you don't need to worry about memory since Android will automatically destroy inactive activities when more memory is needed, and restore them to their previous state when you navigate back to them.